# How to link between a Word document and one or more other Word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create a link between a Word document and one or more other Word documents?

For example, I'm doing a roster schedule for staffs' chores and while I'm doing that in one window, I want to have another window showing something else - say, a table of schedule roles. I might even open a third Word window showing something else.

I want to link between these files; if I'm doing the roster schedule for staff, I want to be able to either press a key or click on something in the Word window and it populates to a second, and perhaps even a third, Word file.

Comment: For future reference, please add what version of Word you are taking about.

Comment: A big help would be what version.  Regardless, this has been possible since Word 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be more specific since I do not have a version, but here is how you do in in Word 2010.

Go to the Insert tab, then click on Object (it is in the text sub-category over near the far right). You will then see the following screenshot:

[image]

Browse to the file, and check the "Link to file" box. You can either update the source file (I would do this to avoid confusion), or if you are in the destination file, when you try to edit it, it actually opens the file within the file. Hard to explain, but you will get it when you see it.

Other versions of Office are very similar.